# Delphi: allow horz/vert scrollbars to show standard popup menus?

Tags: delphi

I use Delphi7. I use custom [memo control](http://econtrol.ru), TSyntaxMemo component.

I see that many apps (Notepad, Notepad++, uTorrent, ...) use standard popup menu for scrollbars:

- scroll here
- up
- down
- page up
- page down
- scroll up
- scroll down

(this is list for a vertical bar).
How can I use such menus for scrollbars in "my" memo? W/o doing these menus by hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything at all to make that menu show in a Windows `EDIT` control. That's a standard system menu implemented by the control. It appears on a `TMemo` added to a vanilla VCL forms app, since `TMemo` is simple a wrapper of the multi-line variant of the `EDIT` control.

[image]

Here's all I needed in my .dfm file:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Align = alClient
    ScrollBars = ssVertical
  end
end
```

This is functionality provided by the system. If your control is not behaving that way then I can think of the following reasons why that happens:

1. Your control is not a Windows `EDIT` control.
2. Your control is an `EDIT` control but it is not using the default message handler that results in this menu.

If item 1 is the reason, then there's nothing you can do to get the system display the menu. If your control is not an `EDIT` control you can hardly expect it to magically behave like one. In the case of item 2, you need to work out how the control is stopping the message that leads to the menu being handled by the control's default message handler.

Comment: I know about TMemo, i need to do in TSYntaxMemo from EControl Syntax SDK (link @ my post).

Comment: Yes I understand that. But we obviously cannot see the source of that control and hence my rather high level answer. You can see the source of the control, and you can inspect it at runtime with Spy++ or similar. Most likely it's not an `EDIT` control and so your luck is out. Anyway, this is a question that you should perhaps address to the vendor that sold you the code.

Comment: Smth wrong with project options. You may close the topic. "vanilla" TSyntaxMemo does have this menu.